# How to calculate the effect size for a t-test?

Tags: r, t-test, effect-size, statistical-power

The `pwr` package includes the function [`pwr.t.test`](https://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html), which relates the following four quantities:

1. sample size
2. effect size
3. significance level = `P(Type I error)`
4. power = `1 - P(Type II error)`

Given any three, we can determine the fourth.

What is the formula powering this function? I tried looking at the code but could not make sense of it. I want to implement an effect size calculator outside of R (i.e., I want to supply the sample size, significance level, and power, to determine the effect size).

I looked at several pages, questions, and vignettes—many offered contradictory calculations or ones that did not make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this related [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13707/how-to-calculate-number-of-participants-required-to-compare-mean-scores-on-a-que/13749#13749). In particular look at Lehr's rule. This provides an approximation: $$n = \frac{16}{\Delta^2},$$ where $\Delta$ is the proposed effect size ($d$). This returns the approximate $n$ for each group. This is similar to @user2974951 answer but I believe is more precise.

To get exact results, you need to work with the t-distribution directly, determining the t-value for given p-values and degrees of freedom, etc.

ADDENDUM:

The approximation above is based on the following. Recall that Cohen's $d$ can be calculated from $t$ and the group sample sizes as: 
$$ d = t \sqrt{\frac{n_1 + n_2}{n_1 n_2}} ~.$$
If the sample sizes are equal, this can be simplified:
$$ d = t \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} .$$
We can further manipulate this for the purpose of power analysis:
$$ d^2 = \frac{t^2 2}{n};~~ therefore~~ n = \frac{t^2 2}{d^2} .$$

In power analysis we are interested in the assumed (true) population effect size ($\Delta$) and need a $t$ value associated with that effect size with our desired power-level. We will start by determining $\Delta$ for a given sample-size, alpha-level, and power-level.
$$ \Delta = (t_{1-\alpha/2,df} + t_{power,df})\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} ~.$$
Where the $t$-values are the critical values for the $t$ at our two-tailed alpha-level and for the $t$ at our power-level, give a specific degrees-of-freedom. If we rearrange this equation to solve for $n$, we get:
$$ n = \frac{(t_{1-\alpha/2,df} + t_{power,df})^2 2}{\Delta^2}  ~.$$
However, we have a problem. We need to know $n$ to know the degrees-of-freedom for $t$. That is, we have $n$ on both sides of the equation. The solution is to iterate through the prior equation that solves for $\Delta$ to find the $n$ that returns to desired $\Delta$ for our alpha and power levels.

Using the value 16 in the numerator of the above equation, however, produces a good approximation. This is the numerator associated with a sample size (in each group) of 52.428. If the approximation returns a sample size greater than 52.428, then it is a slight over-estimate, as we see above on your example (the approximation returns 64 compared to the exact solution of 63.77. If the approximation returns a sample size less than 52.428, then it is an under-estimate of the needed sample size. I haven't explored at which point the under estimation becomes severe but suspect based on where $t$-values really start to grow that it is for values less than around $n=20$.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum—quite informative! Your last paragraph prompts the question—how well does the approximation work when dealing with very large samples (n = 40,000)?

Comment: With n = 40,000, sig level = .05, and power = .8, you have enough power to detect an effect size of about .02 (very small). Working with an effect size of .02, the approximation produces a needed n of 40,000 whereas the exact method indicates you only need 39,245. Close enough for power analysis.

Comment: Wow, sweet. Will test it out but looks great!

Comment: Thanks for this—when testing it out, I realized my use case is slightly different (I have a sample size and probability of success, that need to account for). I'll ask a separate question later on. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To keep it short:

If the goal is $80 \%$ power to detect a difference of $\Delta$, with a study of size $n$, equally divided between the two groups, then the required sample size is $n=2(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)(2.8/\Delta)^2$. If $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=\sigma$, this simplifies to $(5.6\sigma/\Delta)^2$.

To have $80 \%$ power, the true value of the parameter must be $2.8$ standard errors away from the comparison point: the value $2.8$ is $1.96$ from the $95 \%$ interval, plus $0.84$ to reach the $80th$ percentile of the normal distribution.

For example: suppose previous results show a difference of $0.5$ standard deviations, that is $\Delta=0.5\sigma$. To have $80 \%$ power to detect an effect size, it would be sufficient to have a total sample size of $n=(5.6/0.5)^2=126$, or $n/2=63$ in each group.

With R:

```
> pwr.t.test(n=NULL,
           d=0.5,
           sig.level=0.05,
           power=0.8,
           type="two.sample",
           alternative="two.sided")

     Two-sample t test power calculation 

              n = 63.76561
              d = 0.5
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided

  NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

Note that the two results are not identical, but close enough.

So, this formula can be rearranged to

$$\Delta=\dfrac{5.6}{\sqrt{n}}$$