# How to calculate number of participants and stimuli for experiment to reach significance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design, sample-size, statistical-power

I am running an experiment to determine the best performing of 5 systems, labeled A-E. I plan on running pairwise comparisons, e.g. is A better than B, A vs C, etc.? For the sake of argument, we can assume that participant responses follow a normal distribution.

I realize this is essentially a question about statistical power, but I'm not sure how to apply the criteria above either to the `R` package `pwr`, or the statistical software `G Power`. I did read through [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13707/how-to-calculate-number-of-participants-required-to-compare-mean-scores-on-a-que) but couldn't figure out how to apply it to my circumstances.

Any assistance as to how to determine the experimental parameters is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please give some more detail on your experiment? Is response variable $Y$ categorical/binary/continuous? Same question for A,B,C,D,E.  How large/small effects do you need to detect? Interest in any interactions? which? What kind of model do you want to fit? ... ?